# Which differential diagnosis procedure can distinguish a tendinopathy at the gluteus minimus from a tendinopathy at the gluteus medius?

Tags: tendinopathy, differential-diagnosis

Which non-invasive test differential diagnosis procedure can distinguish a tendinopathy at the gluteus minimus from  a tendinopathy at the gluteus medius (trochanter insertion), aside from medical imaging (MRI or ultrasound)?

The typically used [Patrick's test a.k.a. FABER test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick%27s_test), which seems to be a [quite accurate diagnosis test](https://www.tendinopathyrehab.com/blog/tendinopathy-updates/gluteal-tendinopathy-diagnostic-tests) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429024313/https://www.tendinopathyrehab.com/blog/tendinopathy-updates/gluteal-tendinopathy-diagnostic-tests)), cannot distinguish between these two conditions as far as  I know.

I searched for "differential diagnosis gluteus minimus and medius" without success.

Comment: the question doesn't make sense as written.

Comment: Do you mean “test” or “investigation” rather than “differential diagnosis” - both the tendinopathies you describe would present similarly and thus would be a differential diagnosis for each other (along with other things).

Comment: @Chris Thanks, yes I forgot one word ("procedure").